# What statement to decide whether the insert statement goes through

Tags: sql-server

For example, I have 2 tables

```
Create table Authorized
(D_ID char(5), MNUM char(5), primary key(D_ID,MNUM), 
foreign key(D_ID) REFERENCES Distributor(D_ID),
foreign key(MNUM) REFERENCES Model(MNUM));

Create table Orders
(ORDNO char(8), D_ID char(5), MNUM char(5), 
Qty int, Date date,  primary key (ORDNO,D_ID,MNUM),
foreign key(MNUM) REFERENCES Model(MNUM),
foreign key(D_ID) REFERENCES Distributor(D_ID));

INSERT INTO Authorized VALUES ('D0003', 'M0001');
INSERT INTO Authorized VALUES ('D0003', 'M0003');
```

How to I make sure that insert statement to the order table is restricted to D_ID that is authorized? Like if the statement is

```
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES 
('20161232', 'D0003','M0002',2, '2016-12-22');
```

How do you prevent this insert statement from going through? AS `M0002` is not authorized

Comment: Should _Distributor_ table be referenced (I think it should be _Authorized_ table instead)? if yes, you can create a `Trigger` to solve it. or even you can solve it by a `Check` constraint with a `UDF` (`CHECK (IsAuthorized(D_ID) = 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Scalar` function and use it in your table as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsAuthorized
(
    @Value CHAR(5) --I think you mean "MNUM" column here
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result BIT = 0;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Authorized WHERE D_ID = @Value)
        SET @Result = 1;
    RETURN(@Result);
END;
GO
```

Here is how to use it in the table:

```
Create table Orders(
    ORDNO char(8), 
    D_ID char(5) CONSTRAINT CHK_IsAuthorized CHECK(IsAuthorized(D_ID) = 1), 
    MNUM char(5),
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Is it possible to not use scalar? Cause i have yet to learn that